# Angular mat-table using function of DataSource element

Tags: angular, mat-table

I have a table using `mat-table`. In one of its columns I would like to use the result of a function coming from the current element of my DatSource but I'm getting the following error:

> ERROR TypeError: "_v.parent.context.$implicit.getPeriodString is not a
>   function

My table is as follow:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="billingLines" class="mat-elevation-z8">

    <!-- Other columns comes here -->

    <ng-container matColumnDef="period">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Période </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i=index;">
            <p>{{element.getPeriodString()}}</p>
        </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

The component has the DataSource:

```
@Input() billingLines: ContractBillingLine[] = [];
```

And one `ContractBillingLine` is:

```
export class ContractBillingLine {
    constructor(
        public ligneTitle: string,
        public creditNote: boolean,
        public startPeriod: Date,
        public endPeriod: Date,
        public sumHT: number,
        public sumTVA: number,) {
    }

    public getPeriodString(): string {
        return "Du " + moment(this.startPeriod).format("dd/mm/yyyy") + moment(this.endPeriod).format("dd/mm/yyyy");
    }
}
```

I'm new to Angular and not sure what should I do to be able to directly use the function?

I know I could use a variable that will be initialized with the result of the method but my `startPeriod` and `endPeriod` will change over time and I don't want to recall manually the `getPeriodString()` each time one of the two variable changes.

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access the function declared in `ContractBillingLine`, you will have to initialize each object in your `dataSource` as an instance of `ContractBillingLine`. Simply giving `billingLines` a type of `ContractBillingLine[]` will not work as you are simply telling typescript that `billingLines` will be of type `ContractBillingLine[]` while there is no actual instantiation happening.

```js
export class ContractBillingLine {

    public ligneTitle: string,
    public creditNote: boolean,
    public startPeriod: Date,
    public endPeriod: Date,
    public sumHT: number,
    public sumTVA: number

    constructor(
        ligneTitle: string,
        creditNote: boolean,
        startPeriod: Date,
        endPeriod: Date,
        sumHT: number,
        sumTVA: number,
    ) {
        this.ligneTitle = ligneTitle,
        this.creditNote = creditNote,
        this.startPeriod = startPeriod,
        this.endPeriod = endPeriod,
        this.sumHT = sumHT,
        this.sumTVA = sumTVA
    }

    public getPeriodString(): string {
        return "Du " + moment(this.startPeriod).format("dd/mm/yyyy") + moment(this.endPeriod).format("dd/mm/yyyy");
    }
}
```

Example `dataSource` that will work with this

```js
const data: ContractBillingLine[] = [
    new ContractBillingLine('Title', true, new Date(), new Date(), 0, 0)
];

dataSource = data;
```

This might get tedious to initialize, it would be much easier to just declare the function in your component and pass `element` to it.

```html
<p>{{getPeriodString(element)}}</p>
```

Then in your component

```js
public getPeriodString(element: ContractBillingLine): string {
    return "Du " + moment(element.startPeriod).format("dd/mm/yyyy") + moment(element.endPeriod).format("dd/mm/yyyy");
}
```

Comment: How can `getPeriodString()` be a function of my component as it is declared isinde the `ContractBillingLine` class? Btw I tried and it doesn't work, saying: "_co.getPeriodString is not a function".